# Check at compile-time if function has external linkage

Tags: c++, templates, linkage

Is it possible to check at compile time if a function pointer points to a function with external linkage?

What I'm imagining is a type traits-style template that returns whether or not a function pointer has external linkage.

```
void linked() {}

void test() {
  // Returns true, since `linked` will have external linkage.
  bool fn = has_external_linkage<linked>::value;

  auto unlinked = []() {};
  constexpr auto *unlinked_ptr = +unlinked;

  // Returns false, since function pointers to lambdas
  // have no external linkage.
  bool lambda = has_external_linkage<unlinked_ptr>::value;
}
```

**Reasoning**

What I really care about is whether it's valid to pass a function pointer as a template parameter.  The following code fails in GCC, stating that `fn` does not have external linkage.

```
template <typename FnType, FnType fn>
void call() {
  fn();
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  auto lambda = []() {};
  constexpr *lambda_ptr = +lambda;
  call<decltype(lambda_ptr), lambda_ptr>();
  return 0;
}
```

If I swap out `lambda_ptr` for a `constexpr` pointer to a regular function, the code compiles fine, since the function will have external linkage.

Essentially, I'd like to be able to avoid the runtime overhead of sending a function pointer whenever it's possible to encode it as a template parameter.  However, I'd still like to be able to send the function pointer when it can't be a template parameter.  Hence, I'd like to construct something like a `has_external_linkage` template so I can choose the appropriate path.

Comment: It’s a bit circular to use a template to find out if something is valid as a template parameter, isn’t it?

Comment: The requirement for *external* linkage was relaxed in C++11.  You have to be using that for these other features—C++17, even, for the `constexpr` unary `+`.  Do you mean “any linkage”?  Even that is relaxed in C++20…

Comment: You don't need to go this far.  A function pointer is OK.  If you really care, use a function object so it can be inlined.

Comment: @DavisHerring You're right, I don't really care about whether it has `external` linkage, just whether it can be used as a template parameter.  I'm using C++17, so anything valid there is fine.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, using function address as template parameter is UB and you should never use that. Reason is, that for different compilers on different platforms function address may be unknown right to execution time.

That it work on architectures which have VM and assign static virtual addresses to local functions didn't mean anything, since UB allowed to work in any way, even one what you expect it to work ;)

Instead, as was proposed in some other question, you can pass function object by value.

Comment: Undefined behavior is not a matter of your opinion.  The linker participates in assigning function addresses up to and including at runtime.  (Symbol visibility can mess with this by giving one function multiple addresses, but that’s a concern managed separately from basic interface design.)

Comment: Is using a function address as a template parameter actually undefined behavior?  I'd be interested if someone could point me toward a reference to this issue in the C++ standard.

Comment: @xiii1408: No, of course it’s not.  Why would the language have a feature that was always undefined behavior despite being blatantly obvious at compile time?  In current C++, there are so many allowed template parameter types that the prohibitions are listed instead, although there is a [note](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#2.note-1) about using function pointers.